# What is the correct way of using Qt 5.4 in my .deb package?

Tags: application-development, dpkg, qt

I want to create a .deb package for an application that I am working on, which depends on Qt >= 5.4

For some supported versions of Ubuntu this version is not available except via packages from a ppa.

Is it better to depend on the ppa package and have the user add that when installing, or to include the Qt .so files that I need in my own package?

In case of the latter, is it necessary to ensure that my Qt libraries do not go in a systemwide location? For example: /opt/myapp/lib, with a binary wrapper that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH just for my app - instead of /usr/local/lib which can be seen by other apps.

Comment: Is your programm code depending only on 5.4 libraries? There is not too much difference with 5.1, 5.2 versions, are you sure you can't rewrite your app to be compatible with 5.2-5.4?

Comment: If you targetted on most systems support you better to install package under /opt with all necessary Qt libraries, in other way you just better make it available only for distros with 5.4 packages supported by default. Is it what I have from my own experience of building Qt depended packages.

Comment: It needs Qt 5.4. QGlWidget was missing from Qt5.0-5.3